# In MS Access, how do I compare two values (char) so that if they match what is a table, then the value in the next column is selected

Tags: ms-access-2013

I want to match two strings entered in a form. The combination of the strings should be checked against existing values in a table to return a price. I have two battery types - MF and LM. They both have similar battery codes under their respective types  i.e. N40 and N70. (So there is MF N40 & LM N40. There is also MF N70 & LM N70.) All have different prices. So based on the combination entered, the text box "Price" should be populated. How do I get "price" - from the combination of Battery type and battery code entered?

Comment: Its been a while since i put down any code. VERY rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop an expression right in the price textbox just like you would in Excel. [DLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) is the one you want. Once you get DLOOKUP working, nest it within [IIF](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) to avoid an error before a value is added to the other fields.